# How does plt.pcolormesh() visualize a 3D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization, mesh

There is this 3D numpy array `A` and coordinate axes `x`, `y`, `z` calculated for it. The code below is supposed to visualize `A`, but I don't see how.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplot.pyplot as plt
%pylab inline

A = 
x,y,z =
plt.figure(dpi=300)
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal','datalim')
plt.set_cmap(plt.gray())
plt.pcolormesh(x,y, np.flipud(A[:,:,125]))
```

For example, `z` seems to be totally useless. And what's the purpose of flipping the 126th slice of `A`? Does it really use 3D information?

---

**P.S**

`A` is a 3D numpy array generated from a list of DICOM files. `x`, `y`, and `z` are calculated from pixel spacing and slice thickness.

Comment: `plt.pcolormesh(x,y, A[:,:,125])` probably draws slice 125 from A as an upside down image. `x` probably is a 1D array of x-positions, hopefully one more than the second dmension of `A`. Similar for `y`.  Your question is lacking too much information to be suitable.

Comment: @JohanC I think you're right. Just added more information. I'm afraid I know nothing more about this code.